# Replace nested html tags

Tags: jquery

i use this script to replace nested font tags by span tags:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var content = $('div').first();

    $('#input font').each(function(index, value){
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.style.color = $(this).attr('color');
        span.innerHTML = $(this).html();
        $(content).children('font').first().replaceWith(span);  
    });
    $('#output').html($(content).html());
});
```

and this is the html with the font tags I want to replace

```
<div id="input">
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. <font color="#00FF99"><font color="#ff0000">Stet clita</font> kasd gubergren</font>, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

my script doesn't replace the inner font tag (`<font color="#ff0000">Stet clita</font>`). any idea why?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly different approach: [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NN9Sn/1/)

Note, unlike your version, the changes are only made in `#output`, not in `#input`; I suspect that was your intention, based on the names (hence the use of `.clone()`).

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var content = $('div').first().clone();
    var fnt = content.find('font');
    while( fnt.length > 0 ) {
        var current = fnt.first();
        var span = $('<span />')
            .css('color', current.attr('color') )
            .html( current.html() );
        current.replaceWith(span);
    }
    $('#output').html( $(content).html() );
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceWith` method.

```
$('#input font').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $span = $('<span/>', {
                   text: $this.text(),
                   style: "color:" + $this.css('color')
                })
    $this.replaceWith($span)
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek24R/1/)

Comment: the example removes the inner font tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the outer `font` tag is first replaced with the new `span`.  The action actually removes the initial inner `font` element from DOM, thus the second iteration of `each()` would fail.  The new `font` that is replaced is not subject to the original `each()` invocation, so no action is performed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try chaging line to:

```
span.innerHTML = $(this).text();
```

istead of

```
span.innerHTML = $(this).html();
```

Do it if you are sure that `<font>` tags only has text inside them

Answer (score 0):

Try this depth-first approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/C8euR/1/

```
function replace(el) {
    if (el.length == 0) return;
    replace($(el).children('font'));   
    if ($(el).is('font')) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.style.color = $(el).attr('color');
        span.innerHTML = $(el).html();     
        $(el).replaceWith(span);    
    }
}


$(function(e) {
    var content = $('div').first();
    replace(content);
});
```